# how to update terraform state with manual change done on resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

i had provisioned some resources over AWS which includes EC2 instance as well,but then after that we had attached some extra security groups to these instances which now been detected by terraform and it say's it'll rollback it as per the configuration file.

Let's say i had below code which attaches SG to my EC2

vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-xxxx"]

but now my problem is how can i update the terraform.tfstate file so that it should not detach manually attached security groups :

I can solve it as below:

1. i would refresh terraform state file with **terraform refresh** which will update the state file.
2. then i have to update my terraform configuration file manually with security group id's that were attached manually

but that possible for a small kind of setup what if we have a complex scenario, so do we have any other mechanism in terraform which would detect the drift and update it

THanks !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way Terraform will update your source code when detecting a drift on AWS.

The process you mention is right:

1. Report manual changes done in AWS into the Terraform code
2. Do a `terraform plan`. It will refresh the state and show you if there is still a difference

Comment: Thanks Quentin ... i hope terraform will do something about it in future

Answer (score 5):

You can use `terraform import` with the id to import the remote changes to your terraform state file. Later use `terraform plan` to check if the change is reflected in the code.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by updating terraform state file manually but it is not best practice to update this file manually.

Also, if you are updating your AWS resources (created by Terraform) manually or outside terraform code then it defeats the whole purpose of `Infrastructure as Code`.

If you are looking to manage complex infrastructure on AWS using Terraform then it is very good to follow best practices and one of them is all changes should be done via code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can please explain manual update?  i mean even if i fo change state file manually terraform will still detect the drift until i make changes to my configuration file

Comment: Yes, you need to update the code as well as state file.
Code is `source of truth` when working with `Infrastructure as Code`

Answer (score 1):

`terraform import <resource>.<resource_name> [unique_id_from_aws]`

You may need to temporarily comment out any provider/resource that relies on the output of the manually created resource.

After running the above, un-comment the dependencies and run `terraform refresh`.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is technically not correct.

As per my testing:
Terraform refresh will update the state file with current live configuration
Terraform plan will only internally update with the live configuration and compare to the code, but not actually update the state file
Terraform apply will update the state file to current live configuration, even if it says no changes to apply (use case = manual change then update TF code to reflect change and now want to update state file)

Comment: i have to check it again if terraform refresh now updated the code or not but when this issue was reported which is jan 2019 that time it was not doing what you mentioned.

Comment: Just to be clear: Terraform refresh will update the tf state file to the live configuration i.e the AWS resource, however will not update your code i.e main.tf